# Where can I find API which support TEX to create equation?

Tags: api

I know I can use Google Chart API such as  http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl= x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a}  to create equation,
but I find it's not very good, do you know more APIs which support TEX to create equation ? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what API used in http://mathurl.com/ and http://www.numberempire.com/texequationeditor/equationeditor.php